# How to write object in file in java without using object serialization?

Tags: blackberry

I want to write object to file. But as per my study I found that it is not possible without object serialization. Other way is to convert object to array of bytes and then to write to file. But for this also object serialization is required. Is there any other way to write object to file? Because I want to use the same code in android and blackberry also. Please help me, I want to solve this problem as early as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object into a format that can be stored" by Wikipedias definition, no you can't. Why don't you want to serialize your objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write an object to a file, then you by definition want to serialize it - that's what serialization means. If you're just looking for a way to save data to a file that doesn't rely on device-specific storage mechanisms, then you will need to write some custom serialization code. For every class that you want to store in a file, you'll need to do the following:

1. Write a method that stores the current state of the object in some writable structure, such as a string or byte array
2. Write a method that converts the string or byte array back into an object (it will probably be easiest to have this method take a stream as a parameter, and have it create a new object based on the data in that stream)

For example, you could save objects as XML or JSON strings, or in more efficient means - the best way to store it mainly depends on what sort of data you are storing and what you need to do with it.

It is good practice when doing this to include some version number that defines what version of the class you are using, and include this first when serializing the object. That way, when you deserialize, you can check that version number and know how it was serialized. This makes it easy to change your serialization scheme later on while still maintaining backwards compatibility with older files.

If you are just looking for a general purpose storage mechanism that is device-independent, then you could also look into using a [SQLite database](http://www.sqlite.org/) - they are supported on most if not all modern mobile operating systems. This will be easier than hand-rolling your own serialization, and will also generally have better performance.